# Is there a way to fetch transactions on an Anchor program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang

Is it possible to fetch transactions from any account within an anchor on-chain program (rust)? I have tried installing [solana-client](https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/) to use the RPC with `anchor-lang = "0.25.0"` but breaks the build. Is there an alternative? are  we not supposed to read transactions at all within an Anchor program?

If that's the case feels like a huge blind spot for validating stuff :(

Comment: Are you trying to get the transcation using anchor on chain or off chain (js,ts,py)?

Comment: on-chain, I know js/ts and py can.

Answer (score 4):

No. Solana is a state machine. An on-chain program cannot fetch transactions, but it can fetch the actual account data (state).